# Why is there a "potential leak"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

Xcode's analyser is complaining that there is a "potential leak of an object". The first line within the following method is highlighted:

```
- (void)retrieveBeginRestoreData {
    self.restoreContext = [self.image newARGBBitmapContext];
    if (!self.restoreContext) self.restoreData = nil;
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},self.image.size};

    CGContextDrawImage(self.restoreContext, rect, self.image.CGImage);
    self.restoreData = CGBitmapContextGetData(self.restoreContext);
}
```

I have a property declared as such:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGContextRef restoreContext
```

The `newARGBBitmapContext` is defined by the following:

```
- (CGContextRef)newARGBBitmapContext {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    size_t             bitmapByteCount;
    size_t             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(self.CGImage);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(self.CGImage);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    //    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

I managed to resolve this issue by instead declaring `restoreContext` as an instance variable in the header file; the "potential leak" warning goes away.

Questions:

- What was the issue in the first place?
- How was the issue fixed when I stopped declaring `restoreContext` as a property?
- What is the correct way to fix the issue with `restoreContext` being declared as a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
self.restoreContext = [self.image newARGBBitmapContext];
```

does the following:

1. It (potentially) creates an instance object of `CGContext`.
2. Since the method name starts with `new`, an ownership transfer is applied. That means that the receiver (your code) is responsible for releasing it.

When the line of code is run a second time, the reference of the already existing instance of `CGContext` is overridden without releasing the instance, it points to. The older instance will leak.

Comment: What would be the correct way to address the issue with restoreContext being declared as a property?

Comment: Well, this would include a complete explanation of MM rules. However, there are some Qs: 1. Why do you use this method name? 2. Why is the property's setter semantic `assign`? Sorry, it looks like you had a dangling pointer and try to solve that problem by try & error.

Comment: I'm using this method name because ownership is transferred due to the C method `CGBitmapContextCreate`. Isn't that the convention? And I'm using `assign` as isn't `CGContextRef` a primitive type?

Comment: Ah, okay. However, the semantics of the front-end method does not share the semantics of the back-end method. ARC will transfer that on Objective-C code, if the semantics changes. Having CF objects you should read this http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-to-retainable-object-pointer-type-of-expressions-with-known-semantics (I guess that `CGContext` creation is known-retained) or use bridging. It depends on the object type and right now i have no time to check it myself. Maybe i can do that in some hours.